# Google Page Speed Service and CloudFlare - mobile site separate domain

Tags: mobile, cloudflare, google-pagespeed

I have become an access to the Page Speed Service from Google. I would like to use it, but I have the problem, that I have my mobile site on separate domain.

Desktop: www.site.com
Mobile: m.site.com

Do you have some suggestion what to do and to use one of this services to distribute my content to the world and handle the redirection to my m.site.com domain if someone is opening the www.site.com from his phone?

Thanks
Nik

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the mobile site would be impacted at all. Have you actually seen any issues with it on?